# Correct way to source code for screen density related product flavors

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

In Android, there are times when the tablet vs phone version of an app differ to an extent that I need to create entirely separate activities as well as other components for each version. For instance, the home view of my tablet application may have modules within it that are entirely different from those found in the phone application. These differences go beyond configuration qualifiers in layout files.

With gradle for Android, there are two methods I have seen for supporting different source code per product flavor. Specifically in an example with phone and tablet product flavors, option 1 seems to be using a package name:

```
 phone {
            packageName
            "com.ebookfrenzy.buildexample.app.phone"
            versionName "1.0-phone"
        }
```

Option two is to instead use source sets to define either additional code, or a whole new source directory:

```
sourceSets {
    phone {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/phone/java'
        }

    }
}
```

Which option is the correct method? I haven't found anything in Google's documentation and my worry is that if I choose the wrong method, I might miss out on future support for the "correct" method in future Android Studio release.

Comment: What does "sourcing product flavor code for different density devices" mean? How do your options, specifically option #1, tie into your definition of "sourcing product flavor code for different density devices"?

Comment: @CommonsWare updated my question. hopefully more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which option is the correct method?

IMHO, neither.

Option #1 does not "create entirely separate activities as well as other components for each version". It does package your code into a separate APK. Also note that `packageName` was replaced with `applicationId` in the product flavor configuration some time ago.

Option #2 perhaps works but is unnecessary and is more prone than alternatives to confusing the heck out of the IDE.

---

First, you need to ask yourself, "self, do I really need two separate APKs, and all the headache that causes, versus having one APK with some intelligent branching to choose the right stuff?".

For example, suppose that you decide that you want to have `PhoneActivity` and `TabletActivity` that fill the same role, but should be used on smaller-screen and larger-screen devices, respectively. In that case, put both in the same app, and use boolean resources tied to resource sets (e.g., `res/values/bools.xml` and `res/values-sw720dp/bools.xml`) to determine which one of those will be enabled based on screen size. For activities to be launched by third parties (e.g., `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` activity), that may be all that is needed. For activities you start yourself, you'll need a few lines of Java code to configure the proper `Intent` to use with `startActivity()`.

Sticking with one APK file will simplify distribution, including making it actually possible on channels that do not support the notion of having multiple APKs for a single product.

---

If you decide that you really do need two APKs, product flavors are the right answer. However, you would put the size-specific code in [flavor-specific sourcesets](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies), which are available to you "out of the box" with no configuration, rather than hacking in your own source directory.

So, in addition to `src/main/`, you might have `src/pocketSized/` and `src/goshDarnedHuge/` as sourcesets, tied to `pocketSized` and `goshDarnedHuge` product flavors. The code that is unique to the flavor goes in the flavor's sourceset (e.g., a `MainActivity` implementation in each), and the code that is in common stays in `src/main/`. Your distribution channel (e.g., Play Store) may have additional rules for distributing multiple APKs under the same market listing (e.g., `<compatible-screens>` or something to tell the market which APK to use in which circumstance).

Answer (score 1):

you can do this create a new folder of values that is "values-sw600dp"
it create a file bool resources and create your folder "values" bool another resource file, you must create a boolean in each such.

```
"values-sw600dp"
<resources>
     <bool
         name = "isTablet"> true </bool>
</ resources>

"values"
<resources>
     <bool
         name = "isTablet">false</bool>
</ resources>


//in your code you must put

if (getResources.getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet)) {
      // Your code for tablet
} else {
      // Your code for smartphone
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a third option and not really a complete answer. How is this better than the two other options? I see your option as having a severe downside of no clear separation between the tablet and phone code.